# How to echo out two parts of a Multidimensional Array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

The problem I am getting is when I loop through the multidimensional array, once I get to skills in the multidimensional array, it prints out:

`Andrew Wiley
30
Game Designer
72000
Array
C++ Level Design Leadership`

It's printing out both Array and C++ Level Design Leadership.

How do I remove the output of Array and replace it with the skills C++ Level Design Leadership without printing both?

```
$students = [
    Andrew => [
        fullName => Andrew Wiley,
        age => 30,
        jobTitle => Game Designer,
        Salary => 72000,
        skills => [C++, Level Design, Leadership]
    ]
];

foreach($students[Andrew] as $student) {
    echo $student . <br>;
    if($student == $students[Andrew][skills]) {
        foreach($students[Andrew][skills] as $skill) {
            echo $skill;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Quote your array indices. And don't  `echo $student` until you've done an `is_array` check, or your `if($student == $students[Andrew][skills]) {` check

Comment: IT WORKED!!! THANK YOU!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function.

```
function printVariables($array,$level=1){
    foreach($array as $value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            $level++;
            printVariables($value,$level);
        }else{
            echo $level <= 2 ? "$value\n" : "$value ";
        }
    }
}

printVariables($students);
```

Or serialize it...

```
foreach($students as $student){
     echo json_encode($student,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your foreach like so:

```
foreach($students['Andrew'] as $student) {
    echo $student . <br>;
      if($student === $students['Andrew']['skills'] 
        && is_array($students['Andrew']['skills'])
        && count($students['Andrew']['skills']) > 0) {
           echo implode(", ",$students['Andrew']['skills']);
        }
 }
```

Output:

> C++, Level Design, Leadership

What this does:

- If statement checks if it is equal,
- Then checks if it is an array
- Then checks that the array is not empty
- Before finally [joining up all the array elements](https://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) in to a string and outputting that string with `echo`.

*Also note the quotes around the array keys*